# Two similar codes, when they are run on two different computers

Tags: c++

Two similar codes, when they are run on two different computers, give two right answers, but they look different. How could it be explained? The aim is to calculate A+B.

Input: 1000000000 1000000000

Output-1: 2000000000

Output-2: 2e+009

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  ifstream cin("input.txt");
  ofstream cout("output.txt");
  int a, b;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << a + b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tangent: calling your stream variables `cin` and `cout` is insane...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and when you add that to `using namespace std` ....

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using to generate output #2?

Comment: @quantdev I think that's in fact the goal : you can redirect `cin`/`cout` by shadowing them, or not.

Comment: Are you compiling your code on each machine or do you use the same executable?

Comment: On what system (compiler and OS with versions please) is the output 2e+009?  That looks like a floating point representation, which shouldn't happen for the program you've listed with `int` types for `a` and `b`.  Are you sure that output's not for an old version of the program where you used `double` or `float`?

Comment: @Quentin well peut-etre, I don't know who would teach that, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: No, actually both codes were run on Windows 7 Ultimate and we are sure that these outputs are for listed code.

Comment: Then I think it must be caused by differences in locale-specific facets... I don't know much about the details, but suggest you read up - [this](http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/parallel/pgi/doc/pgC++_lib/stdlibug/sta_9169.htm) seems like a reasonable starting point.

Comment: @TonyD Thank you for your reasonable answers!

Comment: I do not think locale can influence if a number is written in scientific notation or not. You have the executable compiled on one machine and run on both of them? Or you compiled (different) executable on each machine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find mantissa length on a particular machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502022/how-to-find-mantissa-length-on-a-particular-machine)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Besides that it might be bad practice I dont see any technical problem with it. The declarations will successfully hide `std::cout` and `std::cin` and if you want to explicitely use those two streams all you have to do is to use them prefixed with their namespace.